# Is it possible to shorten a lot of code which constantly checks for booleans

Tags: ios, swift, function, struct, uibutton

I have different UIButtons all over my view. All UIButtons have a tag and have an image to represent a card. Some UIButtons are placed behind other cards, and can be "unlocked" if certain card has succesfully been played. The way I am checking if the behind cards can be unlocked is as followed:

```
if card1.enabled == false && card2.enabled == false {

unlockCard3()

}
if card3.enabled == false && card4.enabled == false {

unlockCard5()

}
if card8.enabled == false && card5.enabled == false {

    unlockCard11()

    }
```

If any card is been succesfully played, I disenabled them to get above function to work. It does work, but it is alot/repeating of code. I am curious if there is a way to shorten this code. See this image: [image] (left one). In this picture, the card to the right and top from the spades of 10 should be unlocked when the spades of 10 is succesfully played. The left card from the spades of 10 only should be unlocked when the spades of 6 is succesfully unlocked. All those checks and long codes... There has to be a way to make this process easier. Thank you for every suggestion.

Comment: fist please don't use == false or == true, !card1.enabled looks much much better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your buttons in an array and use a second array to represent the relationships of the cards:

```
let buttons = [button0, button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7, button8, button9, button10, button11]

let relatives = [(1, 2, 3), (3, 4, 5), (5, 8, 11)]

for (card1, card2, card3) in relatives {
    if !buttons[card1].enabled && !buttons[card2].enabled {
        unlockCard(card3)
    }
}
```

Comment: This would saved me like hours of typing all those if statements if I knew this approach earlier :'). Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can put all the cards and boolean variables into an array and then use a loop to  iterate through them. Than the main part will looke like this:

```
for (int i = 2; i < number_of_cards; i++)
{
   if (!cards[i - 2].enabled && !cards[i - 1].enabled)
     unlockCard(i);
}
```

You will need to:

- use the arrays to initilize the cards
- probably use indices one less then now (i.e. card3 will become cards[2])
- change your `unlockCard` method to accept the parameter - index of the card

Comment: Yes this would work if all the cards can be unlocked in a certain way, but mine is a little more complex. I updated the information.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is creating Card objects that can keep track of what is locked and taking action when cards are played and unlocked. For example:

```
class Card
{
    //MARK - Public
    func play() {
        if locks > 0 {return}//it's locked - cannot be played

        blockedCards.forEach({ (card) in
            card.locks -= 1
        })
        blockedCards = [Card]()

        //do anything else you need to (e.g. hide/move the button)
    }

    func blockCard(card: Card) {
        card.locks += 1
        blockedCards.append(card)
    }

    //MARK - Private
    private var blockedCards = [Card]()

    private var locks = 0 {
        didSet {
            if locks == 0 {
                //call your unlock function (e.g. flip the UIButton and show the card)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Your UIButton can set a target on the `play` method of the associated card - play will only do something if the card is unlocked.

For example let's assume you have a level with 4 cards A, B, C and D with D at the bottom (blocked by B and C) and A at the top blocking B:

```
    D
   / \
  B   C
 /
A
```

You could configure the level as follows:

```
let cardA = Card()
let cardB = Card()
let cardC = Card()
let cardD = Card()

cardB.blockCard(card: cardD)
cardC.blockCard(card: cardD)
cardA.blockCard(card: cardB)
```

And then the objects would handle everything internally, for example:

```
cardB.play()//nothing happens (blocked by A)
cardD.play()//nothing happens (blocked by B and C)
cardA.play()//PLAYED - B unlocked
cardB.play()//PLAYED
cardD.play()//nothing happens (blocked by C)
cardC.play()//PLAYED - D unlocked
cardD.play()//PLAYED
```